# Is linearity of the quantum state space a necessary postulate in the reconstruction of quantum theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, superposition, linear-systems

This question is about quantum reconstruction.
I am new to this topic, and I decided to read some papers on it.

I selected some works which follow an "information-focused" approach. The authors of these works try to formulate QM through an alternate set of axioms, which avoids the standard quantum state-space structure (in terms of Hermitian operators/linear spaces) and is centered on the idea that the physical state can carry only a limited amount of information.

Some of these authors, after stating the postulates of the theory, use the standard QM formalism to get their results.
This can be done because their “central” postulate about information includes some extra hypothesis about the linearity of the state space. Perhaps in some authors this extra hypothesis is somehow hidden, for example in [1] and [3], see below (but this is just my opinion).

Of course, since their works are on the reconstruction of QM, their aim is to obtain the same properties of standard QM, and linearity is among these properties.

My questions are:
1) When I say that linearity is somehow hidden, is my interpretation right?

2) Are there other theoretical works on quantum reconstruction which follow this idea of “limited information” systems but avoid any hypothesis about linearity? (but, anyway linearity will be a consequence of the axioms of that theories)

Here are some references:
[1] Caslav Brukner and Anton Zeilinger:
http://quantmag.ppole.ru/Articles/Quo_Vadis_Quantum_Mechanics.pdf#page=60

Carlo Rovelli:
[2] "Relational quantum mechanics" https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9609002

Borivoje Dakic  and Caslav Brukner:
[3] Quantum theory and beyond: Is entanglement special?
https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.0695

Even in Hardy's most cited  work ([4] https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0101012),
which doesn't follow an information-focused approach,
there is a very strong "Simplicity" axiom which involves mathematical
properties of the state space, closely related to linearity and
Hilbert structure.

Comment: What do you mean? Quantum mechanics is inherently linear!

Comment: Of course linearity is among the basic hypotheses of the standard formulations of QM. I am talking about different set of axioms that are equivalent to those of standard QM. In the works I cited, linearity seems to be considered as a sort of background hypothesis and never mentioned clearly.

Comment: We can formulate QM starting with an algebra $\mathcal{A}$ generated by observables -- a **C*-algebra** -- and define a **state** to be a map $\rho:\mathcal{A}\to\mathbb{C}$ satisfying certain properties, as described in [my answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/483069). Then the **GNS theorem** implies the existence of a representation of $\mathcal{A}$ as linear operators on a Hilbert space. In this approach, we don't assume a linear structure on the state space (we derive it instead), but we do still assume that each individual state is a linear map $\rho$.

Comment: This post might be of interest to you: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/285635/example-of-non-linear-time-evolution-in-quantum-mechanics/285656#285656

Comment: @BenCrowell Probably you are right, my questions are too vague (it’s not easy to formulate any question without getting into details of the works I cited). I have tried to reformulate them.

Comment: @BenCrowell I've read Weinberg writing about it being nearly impossible to generalize Quantum Mechanics into a non-linear theory but I haven't come across a quantitative treatment of the question. What do I search for? Naive variations of "Gisin's no-go theorem" doesn't land me anywhere good. Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: Thanks for editing the question, this is much better. You probably want to look at Gisin's theorem: Gisin, "Weinberg's non-linear quantum mechanics and supraluminal communications," http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0375-9601(90)90786-N , Physics Letters A 143(1-2):1-2